# How to fix double Splash Screen on android 12 + for managed (!) expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen, expo-splash-screen

Ive been reading through all kidns of post regarding this and the only few solutions or temp. fixes Ive seen were for bare expo apps. Is there any solution for a managed expo app?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "double Splash Screen".  It is great that you are using a Managed app!  So what is the configuration that you think leads to a "double" ?

Comment: Its not my configuration that leads to a double. this is the reason: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate I cant do whats suggested by android to avoid a double splash screen as I am using the managed expo (this is why I am mentioning managed...)

Comment: So your position is that all Expo managed projects suffer from a "double splash screen" problem? Also, could you describe what you mean by "double splash screen"?

Comment: 'my position' says based on what i read that all androids 12 + as I said suffer that when using expo-splash-screen. Again, if it is not managed there are workarounds for this but again, I could not find a workaround for managed. double splash means before the actual splash screen is shown, the one you choose in app.json, another one is shown for a second which is the app icon, therefore double.

Comment: I do see [an open Issue in Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20244) for this.  There are a few "workarounds" people have posted in that thread.  If there's a "native code solution", then I suspect that someone could build a Config Plugin so that people can remain in "managed workflow".

Comment: yes correct, this is why I have posted asking is anyone knows a workaround for the MANAGED expo app.